# Reflection and runtime class to get method

Tags: java

Actually in all my class, i alway have attribute name

Class clazz, Object obj

When we know the object type, we can do something like (if id is a attribute....)

```
Integer id = ((BaseObj) field.get(obj)).getId();
```

Actually

field.get(obj))

return me a object, i search to get value of name attribute of this object.

I search to do something like

```
String name = ((clazz.getClass()) field.get(obj)).getName();
```

Comment: That cannot possibly work, since the compiler still wouldn't know that `getName()` exists.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot cast to a class that's only known at runtime. Either make all these classes implement an interface with a `getName()` method or you'll have to resort to reflection:

```
String name = (String) clazz.getMethod("getName").invoke(obj);
```